# How to make regex only allow one character after a negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I want regex to parse for four digits, with only one comma or nothing after those digits being considered valid.

Valid examples:

- 1970
- 1970 hello
- 1970, hello
- hello ,1970

Invalid examples:

- 1970hello
- 1970,hello
- 1970,,
- hello,1970

I only want the digits (e.g. 1970) to actually be parsed.

I currently have: `(?<![^\s,])(\d{4})(?![^\s,])`, but that matches with the bottom three invalid strings. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to match, but this regexp matches the first three and rejects the last three: `(\d{4}(?:,?($|\s)))`

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify. I need only the digits to be parsed. Also I need the comma to be both behind and in front of the digit (this is new to the question, but I'm having trouble extrapolating your answer to use in front of the digits). Essentially this: https://regex101.com/r/rm5UFE/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one comma or nothing after the 4 digits, you could use a positive lookahead `(?=,?(?!\S))` asserting what is on the right is an optional comma. Then use a negative lookahead to assert what comes after the comma is not a non whitespace char.

If what comes before the 4 digits can only be a comma, but not a not whitespace char before that comma, you can use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\S\S)` to exclude 2 consecutive non whitespace chars

But you also want to exclude matching not a comma before `(?<![^,\s])` to for example not allow `$1970`

```
(?<!\S\S)(?<![^,\s])\d{4}(?=,?(?!\S))
```

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not

  - `\S\S` Match 2 consecutive non whitespace chars
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not

  - `[^,\s]` Match any char except `,` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `,?(?!\S)` Match an optional `,` not followed by a non whitespace char
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IzfGmj/1)

Note that if you need the match only you can omit the capturing group.

Comment: This is almost perfect for my use cases, but one of them fails: https://regex101.com/r/l6nOLH/3. I believe it has something to do with the second \S in the front, but however I try to change it, something breaks. I'm pretty new to regex; do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Hackerman You could make use of a word boundary `\b` see https://regex101.com/r/pg8ann/1

Comment: Are you sure you need that first \s in \s[^,\s]. Seems to work fine without it?

Comment: @HackermanYou can remove that `\s` indeed. https://regex101.com/r/jpSmaN/1 I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your articulation of the conditions doesn't seem to agree with your examples. One possible and plausible generalization from your examples would be **require the number to be space-separated, but permit a single adjacent comma before or after the number** but of course, we can't really know if that's what you actually mean.

```
(?:(?:^|\s),?)(\d{4})(?=,?(?:\s|$))
```

The capturing parentheses contain the number; there will be a non-capturing match before it.

Answer (score -1):

Because ur comma. You need `(?<!\S\S)(\d{4})(?!\S\S)` to match invalid.